# How do I search (or filter) my posts?

Tags: discussion, searching

Is there a way to show only the post that I've written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your posts are listed in [your profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/51325/williepabon). You can look at [all your questions](https://askubuntu.com/users/51325/williepabon?tab=questions) and [all your answers](https://askubuntu.com/users/51325/williepabon?tab=answers) there.

But it sounds like you want the ability to *search* them. For this, simply include `user:51325` in the search box. `51325`, because that's the number that represents your Ask Ubuntu user account. (It appears in the address bar, when you visit your profile.)

If you search for *just* `user:51325`, then you'll see all your questions and answers, listed together, as search results. But you ccan search within that, too. For example, currently the search query `user:51325 nvidia` shows just [these three results](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=user:51325%20nvidia), as they're your posts where Nvidia is mentioned.

When a user's profile is viewed, `user:N` appears in the search box (at the upper-right corner of the page) automatically, where **`N`** is the number that represents that user. So *the easiest way for you to search through your posts is probably to go to your profile, then type your query into the search box* (without removing the text `user:51325` that's already there).

Please note that this shows only posts on the main Ask Ubuntu site. It does not include posts of yours on meta, because meta is treated as a separate site. To see those, start from [your meta profile](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/51325/williepabon).

Comment: Thanks. This answered my question.